# Character Encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, ansi, utf-16

My text editor allows me to code in several different character formats Ansi, UTF-8, UTF-8(No BOM), UTF-16LE, and UTF-16BE.

What is the difference between them?

What is commonly regarded as the best format (I'm using Python if that makes a diffrence)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- "Ansi" is a misnomer and usually refers to some 8-bit encoding that's the default on the current platform (on "western" Windows installations that's usually [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)). It only supports a small set of characters (256 different characters at most).
- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length, ASCII-compatible encoding capable of storing any and all Unicode characters. It's a pretty good choice for western text that should support all Unicode characters and a very viable choice in the general case.
- "UTF-8 (no BOM)" is the name Windows gives to using UTF-8 without writing a [Byte Order Marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark). Since a BOM is **not needed** for UTF-8, it shouldn't be used and this would be the correct choice (pretty much everyone else calls this version simply "UTF-8"!).
- UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE are the [Little Endian and Big Endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) versions of the [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2) encoding. As UTF-8, UTF-16 is capable of representing any Unicode character, however it is not ASCII-compatible.

Generally speaking UTF-8 is a great overall choice and has wide compatibility (just make sure not to write the BOM, because that's what most other software expects).

UTF-16 could take less space if the majority of your text is composed of non-ASCII characters (i.e. doesn't use the basic latin alphabet).

"Ansi" should only be used when you have a specific need to interact with a legacy application that doesn't support Unicode.

An important thing about any encoding is that they are meta-data that need to be communicated in addition to the data. This means that you **must know** the encoding of some byte stream to interpret it as a text correctly. So you should *either* use formats that document the actual encoding used (XML is a prime example here) *or* standardize on a single encoding in a given context and use only that.

For example, if you start a software project, then you can specify that all your source code is in a given encoding (again: I suggest UTF-8) and stick with that.

For Python files specifically, there's [a way to specify the encoding of your source files](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Note that "ANSI" is usually CP1252.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably get greatest utility with [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) No BOM. Forget that ANSI and ASCII exist, they are deprecated dinosaurs.